# split tables into multiple tables every ten columns in python report lab

Tags: python, pandas, reportlab

I am new in python and report lab, I have csv file with 100 rows, I wrote the below script to read csv in dataframe, transpose the dataframe and convert it to list and create table in report lab.
the problem is the created table is very long and I want to convert it multiple tables every ten columns.
the csv file looks like the below table

| sample | type | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | core | 1 |
| 1010 | core | 1 |
| 1020 | plug | 1 |
| 1030 | core | 1 |
| 1040 | so | 1 |
| 1050 | ts | 1 |
| 1060 | plug | 1 |
| 1070 | core | 1 |
| 1080 | so | 1 |
| 1090 | ts | 1 |
| 1100 | plug | 1 |
| 1110 | core | 1 |
| 1120 | so | 1 |
| 1130 | ts | 1 |
| 1000 | core | 1 |
| 1010 | core | 1 |
| 1020 | plug | 1 |
| 1030 | core | 1 |
| 1040 | so | 1 |
| 1050 | ts | 1 |
| 1060 | plug | 1 |
| 1070 | core | 1 |
| 1080 | so | 1 |
| 1090 | ts | 1 |
| 1100 | plug | 1 |
| 1110 | core | 1 |
| 1120 | so | 1 |
| 1130 | ts | 1 |
| 1000 | core | 1 |
| 1010 | core | 1 |
| 1020 | plug | 1 |
| 1030 | core | 1 |
| 1040 | so | 1 |
| 1050 | ts | 1 |
| 1060 | plug | 1 |
| 1070 | core | 1 |
| 1080 | so | 1 |
| 1090 | ts | 1 |
| 1100 | plug | 1 |
| 1110 | core | 1 |
| 1120 | so | 1 |
| 1130 | ts | 1 |

below is the written code:

````
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(r"D:\generate_report\form_letter-16.pdf", pagesize=letter, rightMargin=72, leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72, bottomMargin=18)
p_font2 = 14
divison = "Eduction division"
Author = "Head division,lab manager,staff manger, Student counselor, Sales Manager,Accountant Manager"
To = "Manger,Sales Manager, Sales Representative, Area Manager,Project leader"
Story = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='center', alignment=TA_CENTER))
Story.append(Spacer(12, 36))
ptext = """<font name="times-roman" size="%s"><strong>%s</strong></font> """ % (p_font2, divison)
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["center"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
ptext = """<font name="times-roman" size="%s"><strong>Authors:</strong>%s</font> """ % (p_font2, Author)
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))
ptext = """<font name="times-roman" size="%s"><strong>TO:</strong>%s</font> """ % (p_font2, To)
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 24))

# Transpose datframe, create list, create reportlab table#############
samples = pd.read_csv(r'D:\generate_report\samples.csv')
samples = samples.T
samplelist = samples.values.tolist()
table_test = Table(samplelist)
ts = TableStyle([("GRID", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.yellow),
                 ("BACKGROUND", (0, 0), (-1, -1), colors.gray),
                 ("BACKGROUND", (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.gray),
                 ])
table_test.setStyle(ts)
Story.append(table_test)
doc.build(Story)```
````

Comment: `arrs = np.array_split(samples.T.to_numpy(), 10, axis=1)` will split your `samples` frame into 10 arrays. Change `10` to whatever number of arrays you want.

Comment: it is really helpful, but when I convert list from your code into  table, it reads just first part of  array  [1000, 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050, 1060, 1070, 1080, 1090] not all array [[1000, 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050, 1060, 1070, 1080, 1090],  ['core', 'core', 'plug', 'core', 'so', 'ts', 'plug', 'core', 'so', 'ts'],  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11]]

Comment: Create a list of `Tables` for example `tables = [Table(a) for a in arrs]`